# why mutex lock latency is smaller than main memory reference in JEFF DEAN's Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, low-latency

According to 
http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html

the mutex lock is about 17ns in 2017, smaller than the main memory references, how can this be ?

As far as I know, the implementation contains at least one atomic flag, change to this flag itself is a main memory reference operation, how can the lock be 17ns,
in my test the pthread_mutex_lock function contains many memory operations even without contention.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking that atomic operations imply accessing main memory rather than cache. This is not the case.

Comment: this sounds like a hardware's atomic compare and swap takes 17ns, not a mutex lock

Comment: a CAS is probably the most expensive part of acquiring an uncontended mutex, yes.